# unable to implement recursion in binary tree

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, binary-tree

I just learned how to create a balanced binary tree and how to access them. For example, if this is my tree:
date = ((1,3,None),2,((None,3,4),5,(6,7,8)))
I can create it by given code:

```
class tree:
    def __init__(self,key):
        self.key = key
        self.right = None
        self.left = None
node_0 = tree(2)
node_1 = tree(3)
node_2 = tree(5)
node_3 = tree(1)
node_4 = tree(3)
node_5 = tree(7)
node_6 = tree(4)
node_7 = tree(6)
node_8 = tree(8)
#connecting
node_0.left = node_1
node_0.right = node_2
node_0.left.left = node_3
node_0.right.left = node_4
node_0.right.right = node_5
node_0.right.left.left = node_6
node_0.right.right.left = node_7
node_0.right.right.right = node_8
#accesing
node_0.right.right.right.key
```

But this method is very inefficient and lengthy so I tried recursion in place of that:

```
def parse_tuple(data):
    
    if isinstance(data,tuple) and len(data)==3:
        node = (data[1])
        node.left = parse_tuple(data[0])
        node.right = parse_tuple(data[2])
    elif data is None:
        node = None
    else:
        node=(data)
    return node
```

so my idea is access data = ((1,3,None),2,((None,3,4),5,(6,7,8))) , by passing into a function but there's a problem
the function work well's till node.left = parse_tuple(data[0]). Basically here's what's going on

```
18:10:41.43 >>> Call to parse_tuple in File "C:\Users\muzza\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_17864\3153403204.py", line 4
18:10:41.43 ...... data = ((1, 3, None), 2, ((None, 3, 4), 5, (6, 7, 8)))
18:10:41.43 ...... len(data) = 3
18:10:41.43    4 | def parse_tuple(data):
18:10:41.43    6 |     if isinstance(data,tuple) and len(data)==3:
18:10:41.43    7 |         node = (data[1])
18:10:41.43 .............. node = 2
18:10:41.43    8 |         node.left = parse_tuple(data[0])
    18:10:41.44 >>> Call to parse_tuple in File "C:\Users\muzza\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_17864\3153403204.py", line 4
    18:10:41.44 ...... data = (1, 3, None)
    18:10:41.44 ...... len(data) = 3
    18:10:41.44    4 | def parse_tuple(data):
    18:10:41.44    6 |     if isinstance(data,tuple) and len(data)==3:
    18:10:41.44    7 |         node = (data[1])
    18:10:41.44 .............. node = 3
    18:10:41.44    8 |         node.left = parse_tuple(data[0])
        18:10:41.44 >>> Call to parse_tuple in File "C:\Users\muzza\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_17864\3153403204.py", line 4
        18:10:41.44 ...... data = 1
        18:10:41.44    4 | def parse_tuple(data):
        18:10:41.44    6 |     if isinstance(data,tuple) and len(data)==3:
        18:10:41.44   10 |     elif data is None:
        18:10:41.45   13 |         node=(data)
        18:10:41.45 .............. node = 1
        18:10:41.45   14 |     return node
        18:10:41.45 <<< Return value from parse_tuple: 1
    18:10:41.45    8 |         node.left = parse_tuple(data[0])
    18:10:41.46 !!! AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'left'
    18:10:41.46 !!! When getting attribute: node.left
    18:10:41.46 !!! Call ended by exception
18:10:41.46    8 |         node.left = parse_tuple(data[0])
18:10:41.47 !!! AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'left'
18:10:41.47 !!! When calling: parse_tuple(data[0])
18:10:41.47 !!! Call ended by exception
```

```
I tried to fix the issue but I can't think of any option available. I want to access the data that I've passed, just like the first method above mentioned. I've come across many recursion techniques to implement binary trees but I want correction in this code so that I can know my mistake.
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your code does not call the `tree` constructor. Your `node` should be an instance of that class, yet you merely assign the *key* to `node`.

So change  `node = (data[1])` to `node = tree(data[1])` and `node=(data)` to `node=tree(data)`

Answer (score 0):

### Fixing your `parse_tuple` recursive function

Your function `parse_tuple` is almost correct, but you need to call `tree()` at each recursive call to create all the nodes.

```py
def parse_tuple(data, node=None):
    if isinstance(data, tuple) and len(data) == 3:
        l, k, r = data
        node = tree(k)
        node.left = parse_tuple(l)
        node.right = parse_tuple(r)
    elif data is None:
        node = None
    else:
        node = tree(data)
    return node

parse_tuple( ((1, 3, None), 2, ((None, 3, 4), 5, (6, 7, 8))) )
```

### Tree creation using `Tree.__init__`

There is a much simpler option.

Modify your method `__init__` so that it accepts `right` and `left` arguments.

Instead of:

```py
class tree:
  def __init__(self,key):
    self.key = key
    self.right = None
    self.left = None
```

I suggest to use instead:

```py
class Tree:
  def __init__(self, key, left=None, right=None):
    self.key = key
    self.left = left
    self.right = right
```

This way, you can create the full tree directly:

```py
node0 = Tree(2, Tree(3, Tree(1)), Tree(5, Tree(3, Tree(4)), Tree(7, Tree(6), Tree(8))))
```

Or perhaps more lisibly with some indentation:

```py
node0 = Tree(2,
             Tree(3,
                  Tree(1)),
             Tree(5,
                  Tree(3, Tree(4)),
                  Tree(7, Tree(6), Tree(8))))
```